# Duplicate package variables on SSIS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have a problem in my SSIS package. For the package variable, every time i deploy the project visual studio adds at the project the same variable.

And how I can delete them?

I can see the duplicated variable when i add read variables on the script or when i import the package on SQL Server.

[image: Duplicated Varbiales]

I tried to remove the variable that were in the configuration and re-add them on the `project.params` but when I import the package on SQL Server I have the same issue.

[image]

Comment: I've never seen that before. Can you walk us through exactly what your environment looks like and then the specific steps of how you are deploying

Comment: Check the scope of each variable.  I expect you are using the same variable name, declared within each package.  You should consider using a project level variable instead.